# TFS: How can I configure failed builds history

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

Using TFS `Source Control` and some checkins are failing. I can see the failed checkins details just after failing, but after week or two I cannot find that build again, is there any configuration in TFS that I can set the limit for storing failed builds.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure that in the Build Definition. For that you have to be the Build Administartor.

TFS Build Definitions -> right click - edit Build Definition -> Retention Policy - then you can chosse your settings